# Override parent's max-width from child css

Tags: css, overriding, parent-child

I am using VuePress for docs and for the home page I wanted something more customizable. My problem is that the class `.theme-default-content` has a `max-width` of `740px`, if I override this class and change it's max-width, it'll mess up all the other pages too not only the main page, since on VuePress all pages are linked to the main theme.
What I want is the child class that'll be inside `header` to extend with `width: 100%` of the page.
Currently this would doesn't work, no matter how much I try it'll never override it. I could make it absolute but that'll create even more problems.
Is there a way to override the parent's property from inside?

Comment: To override the parent's property? No. An element's CSS properties cannot be manipulated based on its descendants (with CSS alone, that is). CSS stands for *cascading* style sheets, and as that would indicate, styling can only go *downwards*, not *upwards*. Without any code we cannot advise you on the best approach. Please edit your question so that we can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot override the parent styles with child styles in CSS, as there is [no parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) in CSS.

However, you don't need to override anything to give the child element a `width` that spans `100%` of the viewport; simply use the [viewport unit](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) `vw` as `width: 100vw`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 25px;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Notre that if you have padding on the parent, you may want to **subtract** this from the `width` of the viewport (so that there are no horizontal scrollbars). This can be done with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 25px;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100vw - 25px);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, it was this simple to achieve what I wanted. Now I need to figure how to center it.

Comment: Assuming it's a `<div>`, `margin: 0 auto` on the parent (with a `width` small enough on the child to notice the centering). You can always use something like `width: 50vw`.